# Keep navbar menu on center when adding a navbar brand

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having problems keeping the menu items on center when I'm adding a navbar brand.
The menu items move slightly to the right when I'm adding a logo on the left side of the navbar?
How to keep it centered?
Here is my navbar code(bootstrap):

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://psmedia.playstation.com/is/image/psmedia/call-of-duty-warzone-badge-01-ps4-en-27feb20_1583405365530?$HugeHero_Badge$" height="15%" width="15%"></a>
          <ul class="navbar-nav mx-md-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">WEAPONS <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">LOADOUTS</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
         
          <a href="#" class="button btn-lg btn-info text-center">TEST</a>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the code you provided here is a quick workaround. It may not be the most organized solution but it should work.

You can also remove the default padding in li tags. That causes things to move a little to the right.

Your Styles.css

```css
/* Set all contents in container to be centered automatically */

#navbarTogglerDemo01 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 100vw;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}


/* And all direct sub tags display inline block */

.navbar-brand .navbar-nav .button {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/176837/pexels-photo-176837.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" height="15%" width="15%"></a>
  <ul class="navbar-nav mx-md-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">WEAPONS <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">LOADOUTS</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <a href="#" class="button btn-lg btn-info text-center">TEST</a>
</div>
</nav>
```

Another quick solution, but not 100% responsive:

```css
/* This will move each block slightly back to the left, remember to provide a unit to move left. */

.navbar-brand,
.navbar-nav {
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
  /* Change this to your custom amount: px % em ... etc */
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/176837/pexels-photo-176837.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" height="15%" width="15%">
    </a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-md-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">WEAPONS <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">LOADOUTS</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <a href="#" class="button btn-lg btn-info text-center">TEST</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Please let me know if this helps or in case you have a question.
Good Luck!!

Comment: The navbar menu is now centered! But I have another problem, when I use your suggested style codes, it destroys my navbar in mobile view. nav menus are not hiding and overlapping on other designs.

Comment: It is difficult to know just with that little code. Can I see more code with at least parent containers and elements beside the nav?

Comment: I'm only at navbar, nothing else. simple html tags with jquery script and popper and bootstrap css called.

Comment: Sorry, in second solution instead of // should be /* ... */ . That comment was canceling the styles at next. Besides that, this solution should wok without disrupting your actual design. I already updated the code.